# Join 2 SELECT statements on common column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two select statements such as bellow:

```
SELECT t.name, SUM(t.number) 
FROM table1 t 
WHERE t.something = '1' 
GROUP BY t.name

SELECT v.name, SUM(v.number2) 
FROM table2 v 
WHERE v.somethingElse = '2' 
GROUP BY v.name
```

The result from both of these tables have the common column of 'name' I want to combine the two SELECT statements so I have 1 name column and both the sums show next to their cosponsoring name.

I have tried a FULL OUTER JOIN but I cannot seems to get it to work.

```
SELECT t.name, SUM(t.number) 
FROM table1 t 
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT v.name, SUM(v.number2) FROM table2 v 
WHERE v.somethingElse = '2' GROUP BY v.name) 
ON t.name = v.name 
WHERE t.something = '1' 
GROUP BY t.name
```

Hope someone can point out my silly mistake or how I should go about doing this.

Thank you.

UPDATE: Keep getting error 'Missing right parenthesis'. Have a look on sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b04c4/4

Comment: Have you tried using Union ?

Comment: Just tried UNION and it only gives me 2 columns but I want 3. I don't think UNION is what I need to use. UNION just combines everything.

Comment: U said, you have common column of 'name'. so have you tried inner join?

Comment: I want the table columns to be NAME (common column from both select statment), SUM(t.number) and SUM(t.number2).

Comment: @Safinn unable to help with this, i suggest you create temp tables `table1` and `table2` and `INSERT` the values as the answer. Try the *exact same* query. If it doesn't work it must be of some clause such as `CASE` or `FULL OUTER JOIN`. Can't say there difference with `Oracle`. If it works, there goes you answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the virtual column on subqueries with values 0 and them sum them all by names using union all. Something like this

```
select name, sum(number1),sum(number2) from ( 
    SELECT t.name, SUM(t.value) as number1 , 0 as number2
        FROM table1 t 
        WHERE t.value = '1' 
        GROUP BY t.name
    UNION
    SELECT v.name, 0 as number1 ,SUM(v.value) as number2
        FROM table2 v 
        WHERE v.value = '2' 
        GROUP BY v.name
) group by name;
```

here it is on [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8cf62/1)

Comment: Gave this a go and Im getting error 'missing right parenthesis'. I havnt included the bracket before name.

Comment: Still get the missing right parenthesis. :( Any ideas?

Comment: @Safinn thanks for the sqfiddle i found my error and fixed it, i test it on sql fiddle (see link)

Comment: I don't seem to be able to see the fixed update. Maybe you can re link it? Thank you!

Comment: @Melon +1 Zero values for sum fields and non `NULL` name fields without using `CASE`

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
select A.Name, A.cnt1, B.cnt2 
from(
      SELECT t.name, SUM(t.number) cnt1  
      FROM table1 t 
      WHERE t.something = '1' 
      GROUP BY t.name
   ) A
left join ( 
            SELECT v.name, SUM(v.number2)  cnt2
            FROM table2 v 
            WHERE v.somethingElse = '2' 
            GROUP BY v.name
           ) B on B.name= A.name
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why `FULL OUTER JOIN` didn't work for you, but the following `JOIN` worked and has given the result you expect:

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE
(
  name nvarchar(50), 
  number int
)

DECLARE @table2 TABLE
(
  name nvarchar(50), 
  number int
)

INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES ('name1', 1)
INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES ('name2', 2)
INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES ('name3', 5)
INSERT INTO @table2 VALUES ('name1', 3)
INSERT INTO @table2 VALUES ('name2', 4)
INSERT INTO @table2 VALUES ('name4', 6)

SELECT 
    (CASE WHEN t1Result.name IS NOT NULL THEN t1Result.name
        ELSE t2Result.name
    END) As 'name'
    , t1Result.Sum As 'Sum of table1', t2Result.Sum As 'Sum of table2'
FROM
(
    (
        SELECT name, SUM(number) As 'Sum'
        FROM @table1
        GROUP BY name
    ) As t1Result       
    FULL OUTER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT name, SUM(number) As 'Sum'
        FROM @table2
        GROUP BY name
    ) As t2Result
    ON t1Result.name = t2Result.name
)
```

And the result is:

```
name    Sum of table1   Sum of table2
name1       1               3
name2       2               4
name3       5               NULL
name4       NULL            6
```

Did not include the `WHERE` filter for `somethingElse` column which can be added to *inner queries* for `t1Result` and `t2Result`

Edit : Oracle query for the result on [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b04c4/58)

Comment: Will this work if i added name3,5 in table 2 as its an inner join?.

Comment: @Safinn It will work but `name3` won't be included in the result. Altered `JOIN` with `FULL OUTER JOIN` and solved `NULL name` issue. Check it now

Comment: Ok so now I'm getting error saying FROM keyword not found where expected. I think it's talking about the first FROM after 'sum of table2'

Comment: Are `SELECT`, `CASE`, `FROM` clauses different in `Oracle`, i didn't think so. Try changing `(CASE ...)` with `t1Result.name`

Comment: changed it and same error. Will post exactly what I have in OP. Could it be something to do with the t1table.Sum?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Maybe you can see here better what is going on: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b04c4/18

Comment: @Safinn I'm checking it but `SELECT name, SUM(value) As 'Sum' From table1 GROUP BY name` is giving the exact same error aswell. Removing all the `'` quotes solved one issue but now there's another about paranthesis